# How to cut status bar OR actionbar from a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-bitmap, createbitmap

```
  bitmap?.let {
                            cropimg = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                it,
                                0,
                                56+28,//each mobile has different height of actionbar and status bar
                                it.width,
                                it.height -(56+28)
                            )
                        }
```

I am taking Screenshot of mobile screen and I am getting bitmap as a result

I want to crop the status bar or navigation bar from that bitmap
How to do that? I try above solution but it is not accurate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am taking screenshot of my screen but I don't want the status bar (sometime navigation bar) in that 
So how can I achieve that ?
(I am getting bitmap as a result of ss)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Get the dynamic height of the status bar**

```
fun getStatusBarHeight(context: Context): Int {
    val resources: Resources = context.resources
    val resourceId: Int = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
    return if (resourceId > 0) resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) else 0
}
```

**Step 2: Point out the starting point of your new bitmap like this**

```
          val statusbarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(this)

           bitmap?.let {
                            cropimg = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                it,
                                0,
                                0 + statusbarHeight,
                                it.width,
                                it.height
                            )
                        }
```

Happy Conding! :)